# How to use bochsdbg to debug with asssembly code?

Tags: assembly, gdb, bochs

For example if I want to set a breakpoint at 'mov ah,my_string_address' which is at line 20, how can I do that?

Note: I do not want to set a breakpoint at assembly code which is interpreted, such as 'mov ah,0x7c1f'.

What software should I use? (gdb?)

I have tried to add a line to bochsrc.txt

```
  gdbstub: enabled=1, port=1234, text_base=0, data_base=0, bss_base=0
```

And use gdb to connect to it.

```
  (gdb) target remote 127.0.0.1:1234
```

But I don't know what to do next.

Because I can't list assembly code on gdb,and I also don't know how to break a line in bochsdbg with source code.

Thank you~

Comment: I was wondering the same thing myself. There is a Java GUI for debugging http://code.google.com/p/peter-bochs/ but I can't get the thing to work for the life of me. Let me know if you find any solutions.

Comment: what do you mean by "i can't list assembly code on gdb"? can't you use `disass`?